# Facebook api login not connecting php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My login with facebook api app not returning any data.It works fine with javascript sdk,but I need php one.I have tested a lot of version but couldn't deal with this problem.

**index.php**

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '******',
    'secret' => '******'
));

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
     'scope' => 'public_profile,email',
     'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/fb/fbin.php'
));
echo "<a href='$url'>Login</a>";
```

**fbin.php**

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '******',
    'secret' => '******'
));
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user_id;
```

but it returns "**0**"

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer,there is not any error,but it does not return user id from facebook

Comment: That looks like you are using a very outdated SDK version (looks like v3?). The current PHP SDK is v5, I’d suggest you switch to that one. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted has examples.

Comment: @CBroe, I need this version - simple api. V5 is so complicated.

Comment: v3 was released before the API changes regarding the access token return format were introduced, so un-modified this won’t work with current API versions anyway.

Comment: not sure if it still works, but there you go: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-5-tutorial/

Comment: i prefer using the js sdk though, and do server side api stuff without the sdk. you don´t need to use the php sdk server side.